# cleanup textarea after button submit

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a simple textarea like this.

```
<textarea class='message'></textarea>
<input type='button' name='send-message'>
```

I am using AJAX to send a messages from this from, but since this is not a submit form, the text message still appears in the textarea

I tried to clear up the message using:

```
var txt = document.querySelector('.message').value = '';
```

but this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Add id to textarea:

```
<textarea id="textArea1" class='message'></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("textArea1").innerHTML = "";
```

Query Selector:

```
document.querySelector('.message').innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Is this possible with `querySelector()` instead of `getElementById`, because I don't want to use `id` just for that, all of my tags use class ?

Comment: Yes, Ill post example.

Comment: @robue-a7119895 this will get the first element of the document with class example so if you have multiple elements with class example then you might want to do something else...

Answer (score 1):

Classes are represented with a `.` at the beginning in CSS

```js
var txt = document.querySelector('.message').value = '';
```

```html
<textarea class='message'>
  text the user inputs..
</textarea>
```

Comment: actually, I have done this. I just left out the `.` but still won't work.

Comment: @robue-a7119895 it works fine if you only have one `.message` element in the page. (*added full example*)